# Prove the set $\{0^2 \bmod p, 1^2 \bmod p, \dotsc, ((p-1)/2)^2 \bmod p\}$ consists of $(p+1)/2$ distinct elements.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

**The Question**

I am currently working on the following problem, which is part of a multistep question.

> Prove: The set $\{0^2 \bmod p, 1^2 \bmod p, \dotsc, ((p-1)/2)^2 \bmod
> p\}$ consists of $(p+1)/2$ distinct elements in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ without
>   repetition.

---

**Pieces of a Solution?**

Here is what I have so far that I believe is useful:

1. In the previous part, I proved that if $p$ is an odd prime (i.e., $p \neq 2$) and $a,b$ are any two integers with $0 \leq a < b \leq (p-1)/2$,
   then $a^2 \not\equiv b^2 \pmod{p}$.  I believe this helps prove that all the elements in the set mentioned in the question posed are *distinct*.
2. After looking through a good amount of literature on the matter, it seems helpful to note that, for $x=0^2 \pmod p, 1^2 \pmod p, \dots, ((p-1))/2\pmod p$, we have $x^2\equiv (p-x)^2\pmod p$ since $(p-x)^2=p^2-2px+x^2\equiv x^2 \pmod p$.
3. One other fact that I noticed while scanning the various literature out there is that $x^2\equiv (-x)^2\pmod p$, but I just can't see how that helps me in this problem.

---

**My Questions**

I have been working on this single problem for two entire days now.  Even after seeking help from instructor, I just don't get it.  I have articulated my questions to the best of my abilities below.

1. From what I have gathered, this is a somewhat typical problem concerning [quadratic residues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue).  Despite this, my instructor never taught that topic, and it is never mentioned within the problem.  It seems limiting to not have that definition at hand.  Am I able to do this proof without mentioning the words "quadratic residues?"
2. Why does this set end at $((p-1)/2)^2$?  Why there?  Why not end at $p$?
3. What exactly is $\mathbb{Z}_p$?
4. Most of the proofs I have seen regarding this question have the set starting with $1^2$, not $0^2$.  Additionally, I have noticed that these same proofs end up with the result of there being exactly $(p-1)/2$ quadratic residues and exactly $(p-1)/2$ nonresidues.  I assume this particular set I am given would count the number of quadratic residues if I understand the proofs I've seen correctly, so where does "$(p+1)/2$" elements come from.  Is this a typo?
5. For this problem, does showing that all elements are distinct also show that there is no repetition?  I thought sets didn't have repetition to begin with?

---

**Sorry guys, I know this is a long one but I could really use the help.  Thank you as always!**

Comment: Hints: $x^2 = (-x)^2$, so $x^2 \equiv (-x^2) \pmod{p}$.  Furthermore, if $x^2 \equiv y^2\pmod{p}$, then $x \equiv \pm y \pmod{p}$ (This follows from the fact that $p \mid ab \implies p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers to each of your 5 questions:

1. Yes.
2. Obviously, $1^2 = (-1)^2 \equiv (p-1)^2 \mod p$, so if $p-1$ were included in the set, it would have repetition.
3. The field of integers modulo $p$. (Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field )
4. Count carefully, there are $p+1\over2$ elements listed (start at $0$, end at $p-1\over2$)
5. Yes, you have to show that there is no repetition. To say, $\{1,2,3\}=\{1,1,2,3,3,3\}$, and both set have 3 elements.

---

Proof for the question: (what you already had is indeed useful)

Assume that the set have repetition.

Let $a$ and $b$ be two integers in $\{0,1,2,...,\frac{p-1}2\}$ such that $a\neq b$ and $a^2 \equiv b^2 \mod p$. Therefore,
$$a^2 \equiv b^2 \mod p$$
$$a^2 - b^2\equiv 0 \mod p$$
$$p \vert a^2 - b^2$$
$$p \vert (a+b)(a-b)$$
Therefore $p \vert a+b$ or $p \vert a-b$.

$p \vert a-b$ is impossible because $a\neq b$ and $a, b \in\{0,1,2,...,\frac{p-1}2\}$.

$p \vert a+b$ is impossible because $0 \leq a, b \leq \frac{p-1}2$, thus $0 \leq a+b \leq p-1$, also $a\neq b$ so $a+b\geq 1$.

Therfore the assumption is incorrect $\Rightarrow$ Q.E.D.